# Can't Query Pushed Images on Remote Registry

Tags: image, repository, docker, push, private

- First, I push an image to a remote, private repository (not
  registry.hub.docker.com)
- I can pull that image back
- I can search for it and see it in a list of pushed images

But

- When I log into the remote server, I cannot see those pushed images in the regular CLI (i.e., sudo docker images)

If I'm logged into the remote server, how do I query those pushed images?

Answer (score 0):

I do it in two ways.

First is the registry API: https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/

(Sample call to list images: https://yourregistry.com/v1/search)

Second - if you have control of the private registry - you can install a web UI that makes things even easier: https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/atcol/docker-registry-ui/